# Vagrant ifup eth1 failing (duplicate interface)

Tags: virtualbox, linux-networking, ifconfig, vagrant

I am trying to build a vagrant box from a VirtualBox machine. When I give `vagrant up`, I get an error saying

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

/sbin/ifup eth1
```

If I try to run the command manually, I get

```
/etc/network/interfaces:17: duplicate interface
ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
```

The network-related part of the vagrantfile is

```
config.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.56.11"
```

(if I disable this line and use only a NAT interface, things work, but I would like both a NAT and a host-only network connection)

The contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` is

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not modify.
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
      address 192.168.56.11
      netmask 255.255.255.0
#VAGRANT-END
```

I tried commenting out the `iface eth1 inet dhcp` before packaging the machine, but it didn't have any effect (the line was not commented out on the vagrant box).

Comment: Created a vagrant bugreport: [#1092](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1092)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this:

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/997

Removing the entries other than eth0 in the /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

and removing all but the eth0 ifcfg-eth files in /etc/sysconfig/network/

did the trick for me.

Running virtualbox on ubuntu 12.1, with a suse 11 operating system on the vbox

Comment: the second place is actually /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/